# How to send ussd request through programming on iPhone OS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ussd

How to send ussd request through programming on iPhone OS

For example: *100#

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTCallDialWithID(@"*100#", -1);

and link with CoreTelephony.

Comment: Too bad, CoreTelephony is a private API and will possibly cause Apple to reject an app. But I think it's OK with jailbreak or enterprise.