# Call a GSM Service #123*

Tags: ios, iphone, gsm, phone-call

I want to call a GSM-Servicenumber of my provider, but the iPhone won't give a reaction. When I try the same with a regular number it works.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:#123*1*4#"]
];
```

Have anyone an idea to get the Phone dial the GSM-Code?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478402/how-to-send-ussd-request-through-programming-on-iphone-os - it seems your only option is calling private CTCallDialWithID function from CoreTelephony framework

Comment: @Vladimir thanks for updating ,But is it legal or illegal use coreTelephone and CTCallDialWithID ?? is it private or public ??
can it casing apple rejection for my app??

Comment: @cocos2dman, it is private method and you can't use it in application intended to be posted on Appstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is not possible to use gsm-codes with public methods

See [Apples Documentation about Phone Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. **Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` with `%2A` and `#` with `%23`.

Your example would be:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:%23123%2A1%2A4%23"]
```