# How to call (dialing) with " * " char in IOS?

Tags: ios, character, phone-call, uiapplication

I hope to call with * character. ex> *711313.

Currently, I'm using this code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", tmp];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

I tested two cases:

1. tmp = @"719929292"; //this is ok. make call.
2. tmp = @"*7128282"; //app no reaction. not to call.

How can I call with *(star character)?

Comment: Replace `*` with `%2A` and `#` with `%23`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a GSM Service #123#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346301/call-a-gsm-service-123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star may have to be encoded for use in a URL. Try `%2A` instead of `*`.

This replacement is not done by `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` since `*` is a valid URL character, albeit with a special meaning.

Comment: Yes. If you have already added percent escapes to a string `NSString *escaped;`, you can do `[escaped stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"%2A"]`.

Comment: i found the answer....
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007893-SW1