# Cannot make call to number with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm using **iOS6**, and I cannot make dial to this number: ***222*20#**
Here is my code:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:*222*20#"]]];
```

When I run the script above nothing happens? 
Or maybe, there are some restrictions for dialing numbers?!

Comment: If you are running your project in simulator, it won't call. Check it on device.

Comment: @arthan.v sure, I'm testing on my iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13097737/phone-call-number-with-hashtag-in-xcode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your number contains `*` and `#`.

> **To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports
>   most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme.
>   Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone
>   application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.**
>   If your application receives URL strings from the user or an unknown
>   source, you should also make sure that any special characters that
>   might not be appropriate in a URL are escaped properly. For native
>   applications, use the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
>   method of NSString to escape characters, which returns a properly
>   escaped version of your original string.

Please check [**iPhoneURLScheme**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) for more details.

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek: AFAK, there is no way. Because in some countries the *somenumber*some# is used for VAS offers. If you dial this number from your app, the user will be charged. That's why they prevent this.